# Provide Twilio TwiML in HTTP payload?

Tags: twilio

To make an outbound call with Twilio, you need to provide a URL with TwiML information. Does anyone know if it is possible to provide said TwiML as part of the request so that no TwiML URL is required? That would allow for more more dynamic requests without having to worry about providing pre-defined TwiML URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is no way to send the TwiML as part of the POST to the Twilio API, you have to provide a URL for Twilio to request once the outbound call is answered.

You can provide a single URL that dynamically generates a TwiML response based on the parameters that [Twilio sends as part of its HTTP request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I knew this was the case but was quietly hoping there was an undocumented feature to pass it in the payload, but alas. In any case, I appreciate your response. Thank you!